# How to encapsulate API calls on an Angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I'm currently learning angular at my job, NOT coming from a web dev background.

I'm trying to encapsulate one of my components API calls but I don't know how to even start.

I have a datagrid (built on top of mat-table) component that would provide options like pagination, sorting and page navigation (next, previous page).

Currently, when I use this component in a project, I have to create the service that will call the api and deal with the pagination, sorting and moving next/previous pages outside of my component.

What I want to accomplish is, let's say another project decides to use my component library, I'd love have those API actions dealt in my datagrid itself.

I'm currently following the Services tutorial on angular.io but it does not cover that.

Up to this point I created an `BaseAPIService` that I will inherit in on the services classes that will interface an API.

```
export declare class BaseAPIService {
    private httpClient;
    constructor(httpClient: HttpClient);
    protected request<T>(method: string, url: string, options?: any): Subject<T>;
    protected get<T>(url: string, options?: any): Subject<T>;
    protected head<T>(url: string, options?: any): Subject<T>;
    ...
}
```

Then, in a project that uses my datagrid, we may have a `customers.service` that extends the `BaseApiService`. But how to have it pass the url to api, and config to the component from the `customer.service`?

Is that even possible?

Comment: You can use the `environment.ts` values for the urls. I wouldn't necessarily make a base API service unless you really need it. I get why you would want to, but i would YAGNI it till you need it. You'll want to look at [interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) to manage some of your urls and headers (authorizations, keys, tokens, errors etc).  I would stick as close to the angular docs as possible https://angular.io/guide/http and use dependency injection as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you are trying to build a library to be used for other Angular projects, if that is the case then one possible approach would be to define an interface to be implemented by the library users and pass that to the component using @Input:

```
export interface DataGridRestClient() {
  listItems(): Observable<MyModel[]>;
}

@Component({selector: 'myDataGrid'})
export class DataGridComponent {
  @Input() service: DataGridRestClient;
}
```

and then your library users would implement a custom implementation of `DataGridRestClient` and pass it to your component:

```
<myDataGrid [service]='myCustomImplInstance'></myDataGrid>
```

If the API calls never change but what in fact change is only the host you can encapsulate the calls inside a service and ask for a URI on your component:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataGridService {
  hostUri: string;
}

@Component({selector: 'myDataGrid'})
export class DataGridComponent {
  @Input() hostUri: string;
}
```

and your library user would do:

```
<myDataGrid hostUri='https://mycustomhosturi'></myDataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Marcos.